# Javascript closures - understanding for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button ' + i));
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){ console.log(i); });
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

In the above code - the output will be 5 always no matter what button is pressed because I understand in js it is by referene, by the time the loop completed the final value will be updated in to 'i' - but 1 question I have is why 5 - I thought it is 4 - once the value of i is 4 shouldn't it come out of the loop?? Am I missing some understanding with 'for' loops?

Comment: Outside the for loop assing some other value to `i` – now check it : )

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not about the closure, but rather about the loop, right? The closure is a different story, but the loop is straightforward - it does the increment step before checking to see if it passes the conditional:

The order is:

- Initialize `i` to 0
- _
- Check to see if `i < 5` (it is)
- Execute the body
- Increment `i` to 1
- _
- Check to see if `i < 5` (it is)
- Execute the body
- Increment `i` to 2
- _
- Check to see if `i < 5` (it is)
- Execute the body
- Increment `i` to 3
- _
- Check to see if `i < 5` (it is)
- Execute the body
- Increment `i` to 4
- _
- Check to see if `i < 5` (it is)
- Execute the body
- Increment `i` to 5
- _
- Check to see if `i < 5` (it is not)
- End the loop

Comment: Thanks So much, it makes sense now, I was under an assumption that the loop will break as soon as it is 4 - missed incremented before part..

Comment: @user3645936 The loop breaks when the condition in the second part of the `for()` header fails. How could it break as soon as it's 4 when the condition is `i < 5`?